# 送信専用のメールアドレスについて

Tags: mail

ユーザ登録時に自動返信されるメールアドレスのfrom実装がうまくいかないので、送信専用のメールアドレスにすることを検討しています
・とりあえず、PHPでfromをmail.xxxx.comで指定しました
・受信したメールを試しに返信してみたら、エラーにならず、送信できてしまいました(mail.xxxx.comの設定が出来ていないので受信もできていません)

---

**送信専用のメールアドレスについて**
・「このメールに返信はできません」と書くだけではなく、実際に返信不可なメールを簡単に設定する方法はないですか？
・例えば、example.comのような、誰でもfromで指定できる(かつ返信不可な)「送信専用のメールアドレス」みたいなものはないですか？

---

**メール送信エラーについて**
・意図的にメール送信エラーを発生させるにはどうすれば良いですか？
・メールを一旦受け取って、403エラーみたいなレスポンスを返さなければいけない？
・fromを適当に設定したmail.xxxx.comが送信エラーにならないのはなぜですか？
・送信エラー判断は、メーラーによって異なる？？

---

**試した内容を本文に追記します**
・1.PHPでhoge.yahoo.co.jpへメール送信しました。fromは「/etc/postfix/main.cfのmyhostnameで設定した値 mail.○○○.net」となっていました

・2.上記だと都合が悪いので、PHPでfromをa.9aade.comに指定して、hoge.yahoo.co.jpへメール送信しました

・3.Yahoo!メ－ルで受信しました。fromはa.9aade.comですが、詳細ヘッダーを確認したら、`Return-Path:  <nginx@mail.○○○.net>`となっていました。Reply-to は見つかりませんでした
・どこへ返信されるか理解できていないのですが、取り敢えず返信してみました

・4.Yahoo!メ－ルより普通に返信できました
・「MAILER-DAEMON@yahoo.co.jp」から件名「failure delivery」が届くかと思いきや届きませんでした
・`$ sudo less /var/spool/mail/nginx` を打ちましたが、該当メールは受信されていませんでした
・どこへ返信されたかも分からないし、受信も出来ていないし、送信エラーにもなっていない理由が良く分かりません

5.Yahoo!メ－ルで返信した際の送信済メールの詳細ヘッダを見たら
・`To: a <a.9aade.com>`となっていました
・WHOIS検索で9aade.comを検索したら、「データが取得できませんでした。」と表示されました

※9aade.comは存在しないドメインを指定すれば、返信不可になるかな、と思い適当に指定しました

Comment: 構成が分からないのですが、何処で拒否する予定でしょうか？DNS?F/W?サーバ本体？サーバ本体でpostfixを利用しているならreject_listを作成するとか、DNSならNull MXを登録するとか

Comment: 存在しないメールドメインを送信して、どの程度時間が経過しましたか？また返信に利用しているメールサーバーのリトライの回数やスパンの設定はいくつでしょうか？

Comment: @Sieg。サーバ本体のpostfixの設定が反映されているので、サーバ本体でpostfixを利用しているのだと思います(メール送受信の仕組みを理解できていません)。自分から送信した特定メールだけを受信拒否したいのですが、reject_listだと特定ドメインからのメールは全て受信拒否する感じですか？

Comment: @keitaro_so。メール送信して8時間近く経過しました。「返信に利用しているメールサーバー」の意味が分かりませんでした。うまく説明できないので、試した内容を本文に追記しました

Comment: 私の理解が追いついていないのですが、「自分から送信した特定メールだけを受信拒否したい」：送信に利用したメールアドレス宛のメールを全て拒否するのではなく、そのメールアドレスが送ったメールの中の特定のメールに対しての返信を拒否するということでしょうか？

Comment: 「送信に利用したメールアドレス宛」を全て拒否したいのですが、例えば、「送信に利用したメールアドレス」が「noreply@mail.example.com」だった場合は、「noreply@mail.example.com」宛のメールアドレスは受信拒否したいのですが、「a@mail.example.com」宛のメールは受信したいです。reject_listで検索したら、「特定のドメイン」を拒否すると書いてあってので、上記のようなことは出来ないのかな、と思いコメントで質問しました

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 「このメールに返信はできません」と書くだけではなく、実際に返信不可なメールを簡単に設定する方法はないですか？
>   例えば、example.comのような、誰でもfromで指定できる(かつ返信不可な)「送信専用のメールアドレス」みたいなものはないですか？
>   ・意図的にメール送信エラーを発生させるにはどうすれば良いですか？
>   ・メールを一旦受け取って、403エラーみたいなレスポンスを返さなければいけない

存在しないメールアドレスを設定することが多いです。ただしドメイン（@より後ろ）は存在するもの,アカウント部分は（@より前）は存在しないというふうにしたほうが良いです。（後述します）

> fromを適当に設定したmail.xxxx.comが送信エラーにならないのはなぜですか？

まだエラーメールが届いていないということなので推測ですが、
一般的には、存在しないドメインに送ると一時的なエラーとして送信側のメールサーバでリトライを繰り返します。
ドメインは存在するもののアカウントが存在しないとメールサーバ側がユーザが存在しませんというエラーメッセージを返してくるので恒久的なエラーとしてそのタイミングでエラーメッセージを返してくれます。
そのため今回はまだリトライを繰り返しており、まだエラーメールが届いていないと思われます。

参考
https://sendgrid.kke.co.jp/blog/?p=4123

ドメイン部分は存在するものにしておかないと、メール自体はリトライを実行されて遅れてエラーメッセージが飛んでくると思います。（ご利用のメールサーバやメールサービスの仕様によりますが、）
そのため送信専用のメールを作るときには、ドメインは存在するもののアカウントが存在しないメールで行うことが多いです。そうしないとエラーメールがすぐ帰ってこないし、相手方にメールキューが貯まる原因にもなります。

> 送信エラー判断は、メーラーによって異なる？？

送信エラーの判断内容は一緒でメールが送信できなければエラーです。
ただし、送信エラーの中で一時的なエラーに関しては判断のタイミングはメールサービスやメールサーバによって違います。

一週間リトライすることもあれば24時間しかリトライしないこともあります。
Yahoo!メールの仕様を検索してみましたが、とくに資料は見つかりませんでしたがしばらくすればエラーが帰ってくるかと思います。

Comment: 24時間以上経過して、エラーメールが返ってきました。「存在しないドメインへメール送信」した方がすぐにエラーが返ってくると思っていたのですが、「ドメインは存在するもののアカウントが存在しないメール」へ送信した方がエラーの戻りは早いわけですね。大変参考になりました